# Normalizing curved lines to form a rectangle using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an underwater camera that detects PVC frameworks as in [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPz8W.jpg). I've added random online water effects so it accumulates for the expected rough conditions.

I've tried two approaches:

- Canny Edge Algorithm.
- Multiple color conversions, smoothing and thresholding.

The most efficient result was the later's [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry0l5.png).

My problem is that I'm having trouble preparing this result for further processing.

For easier processing, the result needs line-shaped with constant width as in [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQi3W.png) for the rightmost part.

I tried *Probabilistic Hough Line Transform* to detect any lines but they all are too curved to be detected.

Comment: "a normalized result is one where all shapes are uniform rectangular shapes with constant width" this is not a useful definition since any image can fit this definition: an image is a collection of pixels and a single pixel is a rectangle.

Comment: @Julien I was referring to the detected object in the image as the result.

Comment: my comment still applies. Any detected shape, however wiggly, is ultimately composed of rectangular pixels. In other words your problem is ill defined. You essentially need to determine a "scale" or "granularity" for your "rectangles".

Comment: @Julien Images being of rectangular pixels are common knowledge. My only problem is to get rid of all the wiggle and have line-shaped objects. However, I'll edit the question to clarify more.

Comment: Again "wiggle" might be clearly defined in your head, but is a vague concept. Your current definition doesn't forbid me tell you that your image is not wiggly. So if this answer doesn't satisfy you, you need to come up with a definition that unambiguously defines what you want.

Comment: @Julien Images were already added to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the lines from the image, you could filter the horizontal and vertical lines after thresholding and draw rectangles with a constant width through the centers, then remove the small objects around the intersections:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.morphology import remove_small_objects

rgb = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPz8W.jpg')
# convert to HSV for thresholding
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# threshold hue channel for purple tubes, value channel for blue tubes
thresh_hue = cv2.threshold(hsv[..., 0], 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh_val = cv2.threshold(hsv[..., 2], 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# combine purple tubes with blue tubes
thresh = thresh_hue | thresh_val

cv2.imwrite('threshold_result.png', thresh)

# morphologically close the gaps between purple and blue tubes
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))

cv2.imwrite('closing_result.png', thresh)

# morphological opening with horizontal and vertical kernels
h_kernel = np.zeros((11, 11), dtype=np.uint8)
h_kernel[5, :] = 1

v_kernel = np.zeros((11, 11), dtype=np.uint8)
v_kernel[:, 5] = 1

h_tubes = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, h_kernel, iterations=6)
v_tubes = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, v_kernel, iterations=7)

cv2.imwrite('horizontal_tubes.png', h_tubes)
cv2.imwrite('vertical_tubes.png', v_tubes)

# find contours and draw rectangles with constant widths through centers
h_contours = cv2.findContours(h_tubes, cv2.RETR_LIST,
                              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
h_lines = np.zeros(thresh.shape, np.uint8)

for cnt in h_contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    y += int(np.floor(h / 2) - 4)
    cv2.rectangle(h_lines, (x, y), (x + w, y + 8), 255, -1)

v_contours = cv2.findContours(v_tubes, cv2.RETR_LIST,
                              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
v_lines = np.zeros(thresh.shape, np.uint8)

for cnt in v_contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    x += int(np.floor(w / 2) - 4)
    cv2.rectangle(v_lines, (x, y), (x + 8, y + h), 255, -1)

# combine horizontal and vertical lines
all_lines = h_lines | v_lines

cv2.imwrite('all_lines.png', all_lines)

# remove small objects around the intersections
xor = np.bool8(h_lines ^ v_lines)
removed = xor ^ remove_small_objects(xor, 350)

result = all_lines & ~removed * 255

cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

**threshold_result.png**

[image: threshold_result]

**closing_result.png**

[image: closing_result]

**horizontal_tubes.png**

[image: horizontal_tubes]

**vertical_tubes.png**

[image: vertical_tubes]

**all_lines.png**

[image: all_lines]

**result.png**

[image: result]